# How can I read out Joystick values in Objective-C under OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, joystick

I'm trying to interface with Joysticks in Objective-C, basically I want to read out the analog position values. I'm new to objective-c, and even though I searched a lot, I didn't find a way to do this.

There seems to be a way using GLUT, but the solution should work even without a window open, and I also wasn't able to understand it.

Could you point me in the right direction? Short code examples would help a lot too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for "HID devices" in the xcode documentation.

Comment: Thanks, thats the way to go. Unfortunately understanding the source examples from Apple is very difficult.. But I'm working on that :)